# Referencing a Double Pointer, what is the value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I cant figure out why the output of this program is what it is.  Maybe some one can help me out.

And why does the reference of double Pointer: 0062FB78?

Why does the reference of dereferenced double pointer = 0062FAA0?

Should'nt these be flipped?

0062FB78 is the address of x

I am guess 0062FAA0 is the address of the double Pointer?

```
#include <iostream>


void print(int x) {
    std::cout << "value: " << (x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "reference: " << (&x) << "\n";
    //std::cout << (*x) << "\n";
}

void printPointer(int *x) {
    std::cout << "value: " << x << "\n";
    std::cout << "reference: " << &x << "\n";
    std::cout << "dereference:" << *x << "\n";
}

void printDoublePointer(int **x) {
    std::cout << "value: " << x << "\n";
    std::cout << "reference: " << &x << "\n";
    std::cout << "dereference:" << *x << "\n";
    printPointer(*x);
}

void printTripplePointer(int ***x) {
    std::cout << "value:" << x << "\n";
    std::cout << "reference:" << &x << "\n";
    std::cout << "dereference:" << *x << "\n";
    printDoublePointer(*x);
}

void print(char* string) {
    std::cout << "\n" << string << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    int x = 19;
    int *y; // y is a address space
    y = &x; // &y now points to the address of x, *y now has the value of x
    int **doublePointer = &y;
    print(x);
    printPointer(y);
    printDoublePointer(doublePointer);
    print("doublePointer");
    std::cin >> x;
}

x
value: 19
reference: 0062FBB78

y
value: 0062FC7C
reference: 0062FBB78
defererence: 19

doublePointer
value: 0062FC58
reference of double Pointer: 0062FB78
dereference of doble Pointer: 0062FC7C
value of dereferenced double pointer: 0062FC7C
reference of dereferenced double pointer: 0062FAA0
dereference: 19
```

Comment: Note you are passing parameters *by value* into your various functions.

Comment: calling `&x` a "reference" is a bit confusing. it is the address of `x` not a reference

Comment: In your functions, `&x` is the address of the parameter.  It's not the address of the value you passed to the function.

Comment: Are you saying that because I passed through a function, the x variable of the function deferences the passed parameter?

Comment: apart from `*x` there is no dereferencing and you dont have references. What they are trying to tell you is that the `x` in each of your functions is completely different from the `x` in the `main` (or in the other functions). They have the same value because it gets copied when you call the function, but thats all. Comparing their addresses wont give you much insight other than they are not the same

Comment: so are these the addresses on the stack? Thats why the addresses are the same for all the functions, and the double pointer is acting like a queue.

Comment: yes they live in the stack, though i dont understand what you mean with the double pointer

Comment: If you also print `&x` in `main`, you'll see that it's not in the same location as any of the parameters.

Comment: The reference of the pointer is the same for both the double pointer and the pointer.0062FBB78.  This must be the first memory element in the stack.

Comment: please stop confusing the words. There is no reference in your code!

Comment: The ampersand, `&`, only means "reference" when it's part of a type (such as `int&`). When it's part of an expression, such as `&x`, it's the address-of operator. `&x` is usually read "the address of x" or "a pointer to x", never "a reference to x" (because it isn't).

Comment: ...and please dont get offended. Just trying to help and I find it super akward myself that `int&` is a reference type while `operator&` is the `addressof` operator (which has little to do with c++ references). What adds more to the possible confusion is that in other languages "reference" is sometimes used as a general term that can mean e.g. a pointer, but in c++ a pointer and a reference are two very different concepts

Comment: A "double pointer" is not a thing in C++. What you're playing with here is a "pointer to pointer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going over you problem, let's first agree that after calling `y= &x`, y is not a reference to `x`, but rather the address of `x`.

Now, let's examine the call to `print`

If you pay close attention, we pass the variable by-value, so this method will actually print the value `19`, but the address will belong to a temp copy of `x`.

If we would have changed the prototype to the following one, the address of `x` printed here will be equal to the address of `y` printed in the method `printPointer`

```
void print(int & x) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    std::cout << "value: " << (x) << "\n";
    std::cout << "reference: " << (&x) << "\n";
}
```

Regarding your other concern, these too occur because you pass the pointers by-value and not by-reference.

This simple program shows that everything works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 19;
    int *y = &x;
    int **z = &y;

    std::cout << x << "\t" << &x << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << "\t" << &y << "\t" << *y << std::endl;
    std::cout << z << "\t" << &z << "\t" << *z << std::endl;
}
```